Solving a three-parameter recursive sequence
Consider the triple-indexed sequence of integers defined by
\begin{align} \label{coefficientsV} \nonumber
    f(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)
    &:=(2\alpha+8\beta+12\gamma-1)\cdot f(\alpha-1,\beta,\gamma) - 2(\alpha+1)\cdot f(\alpha+1,\beta-1,\gamma) \\
    &\qquad  \ \ \ \ \  - {\color{red}8}(\beta+1)\cdot f(\alpha,\beta+1,\gamma-1)- 12(\gamma+1)\cdot 
f(\alpha,\beta-2,\gamma+1),
\end{align}
where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma\geq0$. To list them as triangular arrays, choose $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ such that $\alpha+2\beta+3\gamma=t$ for a given $t\geq0$.
To seed the recursion, we let $f(0, 0, 0):=1,$ and we let
$f(\alpha,\beta,\gamma):=0$ if any of the arguments are negative.
Here we list the ``first few'' values:
\begin{align*}
    f(1,0,0)=1, \  f(0,1,0)=-2,\  f(0,0,1)=16,  \   f(1,1,0)=-30,  \  
    f(1,0,1)=448,\dots.
\end{align*}

QUESTION. Is it possible to give some closed formula or a generating function representation of the above sequence?


What do you mean by "set the condition $\alpha+2\beta+3\gamma=t$ for a given $t\geq0$"?

Assume we have to write these numbers in a row, say row $t$. Then, I'm only interested in listing those that satisfy $\alpha+2\beta+3\gamma=t$. Thank you for the question.

But $\alpha+2\beta+3\gamma$ always is equal to something. Another thing is that LHS of your relation has only triples for which this guy equals $t-1$, thus it makes reasonable to consider the sequence of generating polynomials over such triangles.

I understand, Fedor. I wrote something different along those objections. See above.

I get $f(0,0,1)=6$ and $f(1,0,1)=168$, please check.

Seems to be $\ldots -8(\beta+1) \ldots$ instead of $\ldots -3(\beta+1)\ldots$.

You are absolutely right, we need $-8(\beta+1)$.

I assume a typo as suggested in my comments, such that
\begin{align}
    f(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)
    &=(2\alpha+8\beta+12\gamma-1) \, f(\alpha-1,\beta,\gamma) \\
    {}&- 2(\alpha+1) \, f(\alpha+1,\beta-1,\gamma) \\
    {}&- 8(\beta+1) \, f(\alpha,\beta+1,\gamma-1) \\
    {}&- 12(\gamma+1) \, f(\alpha,\beta-2,\gamma+1).
\end{align}
In direction $\alpha$ the recursion can be summed. Noting that
\begin{align}
\frac{(\alpha+1)f(\alpha+1,\beta,\gamma)}{f(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)}
\end{align}
is a slow growing integer sequence for all $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\geq0$, Mathematica's FindSequenceFunction[] can be guided to find the closed form
\begin{align}\label{eq:1}\tag{1}
\frac{(\alpha+1)f(\alpha+1,\beta,\gamma)}{f(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)}
=(1 + \alpha + 2\beta + 3\gamma) \, (1 + 2\alpha + 4\beta + 6\gamma) \, ,
\end{align}
such that
\begin{align}\label{eq:2a}\tag{2a}
\frac{f(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)}{f(0,\beta,\gamma)}
&=
\prod_{\alpha'=0}^{\alpha-1} \frac{(1 + \alpha' + 2\beta + 3\gamma) \, (1 + 2\alpha' + 4\beta + 6\gamma)}{1+\alpha'} \\
\label{eq:2b}\tag{2b}
&= \frac{\Gamma(1 + 2\alpha + 4\beta + 6\gamma)}
{2^\alpha \, \Gamma(1+\alpha)\,\Gamma(1 + 4\beta + 6\gamma)}\\
\label{eq:2c}\tag{2c}
&= \frac{(1 + 4\beta + 6\gamma)_{2\alpha}}
{2^\alpha \, \alpha!}\,,
\end{align}
with Pochhammer symbol $(a)_n$.

If one substitutes this in the original recurrence and denotes $g(b,c)=f(0,b,c)$, we get, I believe, $g(b,c)=-(4b+6c-2)(4b+6c-3)g(b-1,c)-8(b+1)g(b+1,c-1)-12(c+1)g(b-2,c+1)$ - perhaps Mathematica can do miracles for this recurrence once again?

Yes, that's true, but MMA can not solve this recursion.

Can you solve the original recursion in the direction of $\beta$ and $\gamma$ also? Perhaps knowing all of them would help somehow. Or is $\alpha$ somehow special?

It does seem like $\alpha$ is more special among the others, I think.
